# Adding a Button to an InfoWindow of a Marker and transfering the Markertitle to a new activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow, marker

I'm using a GoogleMaps Activity in Android Studio.
Via OnClick on a Marker an InfoWindow is shown.

I want to add a Button to the InfoWindow that directs to an existing activity with fragment containing more detailed information related to the Marker (A short infotext and a picture of the location)

For this purpose i need to transfer the Markertitle to the Detailactivity to fill in the marker related content.

How may I create this button and transfer the Markername to the Detailactitivy?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Info Windows Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows),

> You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

Instead of button, you can use GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(OnInfoWindowClickListener) to start new activity and pass values via Intent.